# Can Twilio Conversations support multiple channels for the same participant/user in a single conversation?

Tags: twilio, twilio-conversations

*Full disclosure, I'm at the very early stages here and have read a lot of the documentation, but haven't yet just experimented with some code yet, so I apologize if the answer is clear once writing some code.*

My goal here is fairly simple, I want to build an application that allows users to participate in a chat with an employee, however I want the customer to be able to use SMS **or** web chat within the same conversation, and alternate freely between the two.

I'm pretty sure I can do that by just making two particicpants for the customer (one chat, one SMS), but there are a few drawbacks to that:

- They get a duplicate notification/text for their own messages
- Their "chat history" is less clean (showing something like "Customer (web)" and "Customer (text)" in the message thread)

So, my question is, **can one participant/user have multiple channels active in the same conversation** and then I (or Twilio) can choose which one to notify based on some condition (e.g. "are they currently online in the web app")?

Like I said, haven't tested anything in code just yet, but based on reading my est thought so far is to "mute" their SMS if they're online, but I'm not sure if that even really works for this use case.